# open multiple sessions to the same remote computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to get some remote logging working, the current strategy is to kick off the remote session as a job and then while waiting for that job to finish, continually remote in and pull from a log file (and display it locally).

The problem I'm running into is that apparently PSSessions don't multiplex, so I get an error about it being busy.  However, in the past I've found that New-PSSession will return an existing PSSession instead of creating a second session to the same computer.

So my question is twofold.

1. How do I create multiple PSSessions to the same computer from the same powershell session, and
2. How can I simply open the above second session with nothing as input but a PSSession.

I can work around 2, although for convenience it'd be nice if I didn't have to.

I get that there's an info stream in powershell 5, but unfortunately I'm not able to use that and it seems as if every attempt I've made at resolving this issue has run into some limitation of Powershell or Windows that prevents it, very aggravating.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about your problem? Why not just return log messages from the first session, why do your need second session for that? Why do you not able to use information stream in PowerShell 5? Possible I just does not have much experience with PowerShell remoting, but I never encounter `New-PSSession` returning existing session instead of creating new one. Does that not working for you: `$NewSession = New-PSSession -Session $OldSession`?

Comment: that only works if I don't have a call hierarchy on the remote side.  If I call 4 functions deep, every single function has to filter the output so pull out the return values and keep the log messages flowing up.

Comment: With PowerShell v5 information stream you can easily send [out of band data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33159772). In early versions of PowerShell you can use `Write-Host` in remote session. Messages would be displayed in local session, although you can not capture them and process, as you can do with information stream.